# Runtime string type names in C++11 vs old compilers with C++0x (demangle)

Tags: c++11, g++

I have an old c++ program that was written on Ubuntu 14 with "experimental" C++0x features.

In that code I used the following lines to get at runtime the type of an object (there are a lot of templates and msgpack):

```
const std::type_info  &ti = typeid(something);
int status;
std::string realtype = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);
```

The original code was full of:

```
if(type=="std::string") ...
```

and it worked.

Now to the question... compiling it on recent Ubuntu (g++ 5.4.0) when I have a string I get:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
```

instead of `std::string`.

When getting to vectors of strings, things get even more complicated.

Obviously I could change the code, but I would like to understand if there is a better or more portable way of doing it.

Minimal working code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "cxxabi.h"

main(){
        std::string s("test");

        const std::type_info  &ti = typeid(s);
        int status;
        std::string realtype = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);

        std::cout << "String s is of type " << realtype << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to get a "good old" std::string output?

Comment: *"if there is a better or more portable way of doing it"* That rather depends on what **it** is. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Your current approach is an extremely odd thing to want to do. It looks very much like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have a framework that sends arbitrary objects using msgpack over the network. Every message has a label "type" that contains the c++ type of the object, so it can correctly be "unpacked" to an actual object correctly.
For example: integers, strings, vectors of strings.
What I'd like to do it's just: std::string s; string t = type(s), and getting "std::string", not that strange odd and ugly std::__cxx11....

Comment: Why do you need to determine, at run time, a type that you already know at compile time? You've just declared `s` to be of type `std::string`, right? Anyway, if, as it seems, you have a finite set of types you need to handle, just make it `std::string type(const std::string& s) { return "std::string"; }`; add overloads for other types as necessary.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: your answer is good for the purpose. I was just wondering why the code that worked with 4.x compiler returned a completely different thing for such a standard object like a string.
The whole thing was done in this way because the receiving and the sending program are loosely coupled, so it's not always clear what type of objects you will receive. And in this way most of the code was written in template format.